# fread performance and shinnyapp

Tags: fread, shiny

I have a shinny app that has to read big tables that are provided by the client and perform some calculations.
For this reason I use fread within the following function

```
read_shiny_files=function(path){  
  file = data.table::fread(path,stringsAsFactors =  F,header=TRUE,data.table=FALSE,skip=0)
  rownames(file)=make.names(samples(file[,1]),unique=TRUE)
  file=file[,-1] 
  return(file)
}
```

Then I allow for some data preprocessing based on users parameters

```
read_files=function(features_list,rm,rmv,im,imv,nr){

  features_list=lapply(features_list,read_shiny_files)  
  #remove rows and columns with more than rmv missing values
  if(rm==TRUE) features_list=lapply(features_list,remove_missing,rmv)  
  #impute based on imv neighbours. Method based on Troyanskaya et al
  if(im==TRUE) features_list=lapply(features_list,function(x,imv) t(impute.knn(t(x),k=imv)$data),imv) 
  if(nr==TRUE) features_list=lapply(features_list,standardNormalization)

 return(features_list)                                  
}
```

Running this function in RStudio for a table of 20M takes not more than 2 secs
But with Shiny takes definitely much more time (almost a min). This happen whether run it locally with RunApp or I use it on the shinyapp.io web app
Can u help me to improve speed?

here is what I ve written

```
> fl=reactive({
>     validate(
>       need(input$files$datapath != "", "Please select a data set")
>     )    read_files(features_list=input$files$datapath,input$rm,input$rmv,input$im,input$imv,input$nr)
> })
```

PS

I also change parameters in server.R to change tables max size (5M the limit)

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using data.tables and fread in my shiny app, but I do not see the loss of performance you indicate.

As you do not provide a reproducible example, I will just comment on the basis of my experience.

- fread is part of the data.table library and its output is a data.table (you can set in the function call appropriate options if you want a data.frame output
  etc.).
- With a large table the effort is to minimise chances of R    taking
  copies of your table: I would avoid to use functions unless absolutely necessary, but I would do any manipulation within the shiny function you are using
  in that moment.
- On the same vein I would *only* remove columns with the `:=` operator.
  Sadly if you need to remove rows the `:=` operator is not yet available and you do need to copy but the `[` operator should be faster than lapply.

In conclusion I would do all manipulations of the data.table building the data.table expression dynamically (great technique suggested by Matt Doyle).

this is an example from my code:

```
str <- paste0("cal_[dtf_,allow.cartesian=TRUE][, ftehours := sum(fteSum),by=c('", appTime_,
          "', 'subfunctionname')]")
dtf_ <- eval(parse(text= str))
```